# How to make natural batching on Flux?

Tags: project-reactor

Is there any easy way to make natural batching (smart batching) on Flux?

What is natural batching (read more here: https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/10/smart-batching.html )?

Batching, which is done in single thread with end-less loop like:

1. collect all items in queue (at least single item)
2. do operation on them (batch insert into DB for example)

This would mean that logic of project reactor is a bit "reversed". Instead of "take(x)", we need to collect things in buffer, while doing operations on previous batch and limit how match items to "pre-fetch" for next batch.

PS: I would expect some info here https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-three-sorts-batching about natural batching

PS2: Is would make some Publisher to achieve this  behavior perhaps. Is this OK approach?

Comment: Naively, I would say that a simple `Flux.buffer(...).flatMap(...)` combination would produce "natural" batching, because Reactor effectively uses internal queues and subscription/backpressure management to allow producers and consumers to work concurrently. There's a lot of options to manage internal buffering and producer limit rate. I might try to make an example in a few days, but I need time to understand how to properly prove that a flow has a right behavior regarding natural batching.